# How can I make a View Item readonly AND scrollable in Enthought Traitsui?

Tags: python, enthought, traitsui

I am using the views in Enthought Traitsui.  Within a view, I am using `Item('strings', enabled_when='len(x)>20')`, where `'strings'` is a list of strings and `len(x)>20` is never true. If there are more than three strings in the list, I cannot see them all. I would like to be able to scroll through all the strings but at the same time not be allowed to edit the strings. Does anybody know if I can have a readonly AND scrollable item, and if not what are the alternatives?
Thank you.

Comment: Why is this problematic? `ListEditor` and `ListStrEditor` have readonly styles. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why would you want `enabled_when='len(x)>20'` if `len(x)>20` is never true? Are you using this as a way to get a readonly editor?

Comment: @aestrivex Thank you for your comments. I had tried several things but not ListEditor. I was using "enabled_when='len(x)>20'" to get a readonly editor. With ListEditor, I am able to get a readonly style AND I am able to scroll through the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a way to customize the editor.  Here's the general idea in a minimal example:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, List
from traitsui.api import View, ListEditor, Group, Item


class Foo(HasTraits):
    my_list = List()

    def _my_list_default(self):
        return [str(n) for n in range(6)]

    traits_view = View(
        Item('my_list',
            style='custom',
            editor=ListEditor(
                style='text',
                ),
        ),
        height=100,
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo()
    f.configure_traits()
```

[image: sample UI]

You can look in the TraitsUI docs to find lots of ways to customize the view with different editor factories.  You can change `style='readonly'` for instance to prevent editing.